# Let $S$ be a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with area 5, and let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 8 \\ 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix}.$ Find the area of the region $AS$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $S$ be a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with area 5, and let
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 8 \\ 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Find the area of the region $AS$.

---

I'm not sure how the matrix moves the region.  All help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\det$...

Comment: A $2\times 2$ matrix is a linear function between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and itself. The question asked is about the area of the image of the region $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to calculate where the region moves, you use the fact that $$\text{Area of AS}=|\det A|\times(\text{Area of S})=14\times 5=70$$

Comment: $14 \times 5 =70$

Comment: @YunaKun Haha whoops. Corrected